# Google Analytics Number of Requests Exceeded Exception

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am developing a website where I am integrating Google Analytics in the project. All is working fine but sometimes I get the error that "Number of Requests Limit exceeded. Please signup to Google Developers console" something like that. I have searched the internet and they have described that obtain the "Client ID" from Google Developers Console.

I have done that but now I cannot find that where to put that "Client ID" in the API file? I am using the "gapi" class for fetching the Google Analytics data. But in the "gapi.class.php" file there is no option for the "Client ID" which I have obtained from Google Developers Console.

Where to put the "client ID" OR there is something I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're using GA to track your website or fetch data from GA? That's 2 different things.

Comment: I am doing both tracking and then fetching data to display on my website. When displaying data on my website only then the exception is thrown of limit exceeded.

Comment: Yes, if you fetch data from GA, you'll require an API key from Google API Console. Go get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using [this library](https://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) which is a third party library that authenticate the user through email/password in order to access his analytics account.

If you need to access the GA API as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/) maybe you will have to use another library. Google is providing a [PHP library](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries) to access the API. Also, if you look at the code samples you will see that they are using the API KEY and the Client ID to authenticate (the Client ID is not always needed depending on what you are requesting).

Comment: So I have to move from third Party library to one that Google supplies right?

Comment: yes, I think, because if you look at gapi.class.php code you will see that there is only one auth mecanism through a Google Account email and password, and no auth mecanism through an API, with a Client ID and an API key. So, it seems that you cannot use the official API with this library

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support.